# If query results matches any value from another query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries generating panel ids. One query generates only panel ids related to a product. The other query generates all the available panel ids.

I am trying to display all the panels via check-boxes but have the related panels show as checked. I have stored the related panel in `$panel_id` However, the following code seems to only loop once since it only checks only one of the related panels. I'm not sure what I should do.

```
//related panels
$panel_id = $row['panel_profile_id'];


/all panels
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM panel_profile");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['panel_profile_id'] == $panel_id) { 
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="panel_profile[]" value="' . $row['panel_profile_id'] . '" checked="checked">' . $row['name'] . '<br />';
    } else {
        echo  '<input type="checkbox" name="panel_profile[]" value="' . $row['panel_profile_id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

**Table Structures**

Table: panel_table

```
panel_profile_id | name
-----------------+-----
1                | flat
```

Table: relationship_table

```
wood_species_id | panel_profile_id
----------------+-----------------
1               | 1
```

Comment: can you post the structure of your 2 tables ?

Comment: not sure how to style tables on here

Comment: which table has the panel_profile_id field ?

Comment: both tables have them

Comment: oh...ok my bad...I see them ...

Comment: where is the structure for panel_profile table ?

Comment: The first table is the panel_profile table

Comment: it looks good. What exactly is not working? are you getting any error ?

Comment: @izharbuen then why do you call it panel_table? what is the actual table name? And again, what errors if any are you getting. The code looks to be functional.

Comment: I have more than one panel for each wood_id but it only shows one box as checked

Answer (score 2):

You could let the database do the work for you by using a left join to select which panel_ids should be checked.

For example,

If the following returned the list of panel profiles you want to be checked,

```
  SELECT panel_profile_id FROM relationship_table WHERE wood_species_id=4
```

you could use

```
 SELECT panel_profile.panel_profile_id,
        (products.panel_profile_id IS NOT NULL) AS checked
   FROM panel_profile LEFT JOIN relationship_table
     ON panel_profile.panel_profile_id=products.panel_profile_id
  WHERE wood_species_id=4
```

This query returns two columns, the panel_profile_id and a checked column with 1 if it should be checked and 0 if it should not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the panels corresponding to the product and then mark those panels as checked like this:

```
SELECT *, panel_profile_id IN (SELECT panel_profile_id FROM relationship_table WHERE wood_species_id = 2) as checked
FROM panel_table
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45272/10)**